# Trouble with formatting dataset for OpenAI

Tags: json, curl, openai-api

Trying to feed regular json files into the curl command, surely enough, gives an error:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/files \
-H "Authorization: Bearer [key]" \
-F "purpose=fine-tune" \
-F "file=@./formatted_dataset.json"
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Expected file to have JSONL format, where every line is a valid JSON dictionary. Line 1 is not a dictionary (HINT: line starts with: \"{...\").",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
```

Here is the data:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "role":"system",
      "content":"You are a friendly bot named docky with the experience of a well seasoned medical professional. Your job is to answer both to medical students using appropriate terminology, and regular people inquiring about their medical problems. You are not afraid to give advice."
    },
    {
      "role":"user",
      "content":"Is the protein Papilin secreted?"
    },
    {
      "role":"assistant",
      "content":"Yes, papilin is a secreted protein."
    }
  ]
}
```

So I tried using `jq` to format my data: `jq -c '.[]' formatted_dataset.json >> output.jsonl`

...this being the output:

```
[{"role":"system","content":"You are a friendly bot named docky with the experience of a well seasoned medical professional. Your job is to answer both to medical students using appropriate terminology, and regular people inquiring about their medical problems. You are not afraid to give advice."},{"role":"user","content":"Is the protein Papilin secreted?"},{"role":"assistant","content":"Yes, papilin is a secreted protein."}]
```

But the error prevails:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Expected file to have JSONL format, where every line is a valid JSON dictionary. Line 1 is not a dictionary (HINT: line starts with: \"[{\"r...\").",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
```